# AWS Elastic Load Balancer HTTP health check ping not reaching Rails application server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, elastic-beanstalk, healthcheck

I have just inherited a Ruby + Rails application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and it is currently using TCP for the Elastic Load Balancer health check. I wish to switch to HTTP, and actually hit my application.

To do this I creat an endpoint on the application that always returns status 200. I deploy this, and test it with curl.

```
louis $ curl -I https://my.domain.goes.here/__status__
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2015 16:09:29 GMT
ETag: W/"028714d01e3aa7ed0ffa7a023f82ca94"
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Request-Id: 1ce6b907-779a-45d2-b9f9-d19a74ef8abd
X-Runtime: 0.002703
Connection: keep-alive
```

This is the result I expected.

I use the AWS console to set up the health check with the following configuration:

```
Ping Target          HTTP:80/__status__
Timeout              5 seconds
Interval             30 seconds
Unhealthy Threshold  5
Healthy Threshold    3
```

But now the health check fails consistently. The same for HTTPS on port 443

I ssh into the instance and curl from there.

```
# With the "Private IP"
[ec2-user@ip-$PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS ~]$ curl -I $PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS/__status__
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2015 08:14:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://$PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS/__status__

# With the "Private DNS"
[ec2-user@ip-$PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS ~]$ curl -I $PRIVATE_DNS_ADDRESS/__status__
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2015 08:17:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://$PRIVATE_DNS_ADDRESS/__status__

# With the "Public IP"
[ec2-user@ip-$PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS ~]$ curl -I $PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS/__status__
curl: (7) Failed to connect to $PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS port 80: Connection timed out

# With the "Public DNS"
[ec2-user@ip-$PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS ~]$ curl -I $PUBLIC_DNS_ADDRESS/__status__
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2015 07:24:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://$PUBLIC_DNS_ADDRESS/__status__

# With the "Public DNS" over HTTPS
[ec2-user@ip-$PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS ~]$ curl -I https://$PUBLIC_DNS_ADDRESS/__status__
curl: (7) Failed to connect to $PUBLIC_DNS_ADDRESS port 443: Connection refused
```

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ELB will not hit your domain name, it'll hit your IP address. Test `curl -I https://my.**IP**.goes.here/__status__` to verify your status check works properly - it'll hit the default vhost.

**edit:** Per your updated results, your server is redirecting your HTTP accesses to HTTPS. ELB doesn't consider a 301 a success, so it's treating it as a failure. Exempt your status page from the HTTP → HTTPS redirect.

Comment: Is that the IP of the EC2 instance?

Comment: @lpil Yes, the IP of the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you. It has "VPC ID", which I thought meant it could not be accessed from outside the VPC. curling either the "Public DNS" address or the "Public IP" on port 80 fails with the connection being refused (after some wait).

Comment: Do the curl from the instance itself. The ELB will be able to access it (assuming the ELB has been given the appropriate security group settings) from within the VPC in a similar manner.

Comment: I have updated the post with the results, thank you.

Comment: @lpil Updated my answer. You're serving a 301 from HTTP to HTTPS. ELB considers only 2xx responses to be successes.